# C# Create Snap To Grid Functionality

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime

I am trying to create some snap to grid functionality to be used at run time but I am having problems with the snapping part.  I have successfully drawn a dotted grid on a panel but when I add a label control to the panel how to I snap the top, left corner of the label to the nearest dot?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pos.x - pos.x % gridWidth` should do it.

Comment: Kepp in mind that the above code will snap to the gridline closer to zero though. To snap left or right you could i.e. test wether pos.x % gridWidth is more or less than gridWidth / 2. Remember that you'll get a different case for coordinates below zero. That should give you all the tools you need.

Comment: if you have gridWidth = 3. for a pointX = 5, it will map to 3 when it should map to 6. see my answer for more elaborate answer.

Comment: This is equivalent to rounding down, which is not always the desired result. Rounding to the nearest grid vertex is the best option, check out @numansalati 's answer below!

Answer (score 21):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct. Here is why:

if the gridwidth = 3, the a point on x like 4 should map to 3 but x=5 should map to 6. using Pedery's answer they will both map to 3.

For correct result you need to round off like this (you can use float if points are fractions):

//Lets say.

```
int gridCubeWidth  = 3;
int gridCubeHeight = 3;

int newX = Math.Round(oldX / gridCubeWidth)  * gridCubeWidth;
int newY = Math.Round(oldY / gridCubeHeight) * gridCubeHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks — this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

This one works better for me as it moves the point depending on how close it is to next or previous gird-point:

```
            if (pt.X % gridWidth < gridWidth/2)
                pt.X = pt.X - pt.X % gridWidth;
            else
                pt.X = pt.X + (gridWidth - pt.X % gridWidth);

            if (pt.Y % gridHeight < gridHeight / 2)
                pt.Y = pt.Y - pt.Y % gridHeight;
            else
                pt.Y = pt.Y + (gridHeight - pt.Y % gridHeight);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that **rounds** to the nearest grid point:

```
    public static readonly Size  Grid     = new Size( 16, 16 );
    public static readonly Size  HalfGrid = new Size( Grid.Width/2, Grid.Height/2 );

    // ~~~~ Round to nearest Grid point ~~~~
    public Point  SnapCalculate( Point p )
    {
        int     snapX = ( ( p.X + HalfGrid.Width  ) / Grid.Width  ) * Grid.Width;
        int     snapY = ( ( p.Y + HalfGrid.Height ) / Grid.Height ) * Grid.Height;

        return  new Point( snapX, snapY );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private enum SnapMode { Create, Move }
private Size gridSizeModeCreate = new Size(30, 30);
private Size gridSizeModeMove = new Size(15, 15);

private Point SnapCalculate(Point p, Size s)
{
    double snapX = p.X + ((Math.Round(p.X / s.Width) - p.X / s.Width) * s.Width);
    double snapY = p.Y + ((Math.Round(p.Y / s.Height) - p.Y / s.Height) * s.Height);
    return new Point(snapX, snapY);
}

private Point SnapToGrid(Point p, SnapMode mode)
{
    if (mode == SnapMode.Create)
        return SnapCalculate(p, gridSizeModeCreate);
    else if (mode == SnapMode.Move)
        return SnapCalculate(p, gridSizeModeMove);
    else
        return new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use integers and division will just work for you:

```
int xSnap = (xMouse / gridWidth) * gridWidth;
int ySnap = (yMouse / gridHeight) * gridHeight;
```

Except of course the modulo solution is so much more elegant.

Comment: You are multiplying and dividing by gridWidth. This will cancel them out leaving this to always equal xMouse.

Comment: -1: as @Julian said, elementary math shows that this answer is nonsense

Comment: Computation is not an elementary math. When result of "(xMouse/gridWidth)" is an integer then this formula works just fine.